# Hashing to derive unique IDs

Tags: python, hash, unique-id

In a dataset, is hashing two attributes' unique IDs of an observation (a row) a correct method of creating a unique ID for the observation, given that that observation's uniqueness is derived from said attributes' cooccurrence?

Sample of data looks like:

```
   scenario_id  procedure_spvid
0         2986           114374
1         2986           114660
2         2986           128564
3         2986           125072

scenario_id:
  min, max: 25, 5100306
  count unique: 2629
procedure_spvid:
  min, max: 2, 9000057
  count unique: 1163
```

However, the ID's are not contiguous, ie there are not 5,100,306 scenarios.

And what I'm doing down the dataset, in Python, is:

```
hex(hash((scenario_id,procedure_spvid)))
```

Comment: In general, "hashing" and "unique" are incompatible. There is always the possibility, however small, of a duplicate. I can't say if your particular case is an exception to that rule. You need to provide a more concrete example. Include the size of your IDs and the number of IDs, and the scope of the hash.

Comment: Yea, I thought there might be a possibility of duplicates. I updated my question with stats. If you can share the basics of how I can determine whether the hashes will be unique, much appreciated. Or maybe another method is superior.

Comment: What are you doing with the hash? You might be better off just using the `(scenario_id,procedure_spvid)` tuple

Comment: My ultimate goal is to label duplicate observations (rows). Duplicates concerning scenario_id and procedure_spvid. I don't want to just drop duplicates--yet. I need to show stakeholders the current state of the data, and having a unique ID for each unique scenario-procedure pair might help this.

Comment: If you need to hide the values of the (s,p) pair, and you want to use a function rather than a (id,s,p) table, you will want to know what a psuedorandom permutation (PRP) is.

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of a hash is not to guarantee uniqueness, but to provide a *reasonable probability* of uniqueness when the "proof" you would otherwise need is larger than the space you have to store it.

The only *truly* unique way to store the unique pair of `(sid, pid)` is by grafting them onto each other, either via a string, tuple, etc. But if `sid` and `pid` were each, say, 4 bytes, you would need a minimum of 8 bytes to do that. If you wanted to use only 4 bytes, you could use a 4-byte hash of `(sid, pid)` - but because you're fitting more than 4 bytes' worth of possible options into only 4 bytes, there's a certain possibility of duplicates. Mathematically, this is known as the [pigeonhole principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle).

If you're using a database, there's probably a way to designate a [compound key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compound_key) that includes both columns, so that *together* they provide a primary key for the rest of the row. If you're using a hashtable in a proper language (e.g. a python `dict`), then that data structure will keep track of duplicate hashes and accommodate for them so that they don't return the same value.

If you're using a hash, and managing it yourself, then you have to accept the possibility of conflict.

Without seeing your dataset in particular, we can't really troubleshoot *why* you might be seeing duplicate hashes, however.

Comment: If by grafting you mean concatenate into a string, then my thought was that it would be somewhat likely to create two of the same IDs, eg [12,3]=123 and [1,23]=123. As a tuple, would it just look like '12,3'? I was hoping to have a more standard format without a comma.

Comment: Concatenation would be one method. Simply putting the integer bytes next to each other (e.g. forming one 8-byte integer out of two 4-byte integers) would be another, although that would be a language-specific affair. Ideally you would store it as a 2-tuple the way it's already stored, but otherwise, string concatenation with a single separator character should do fine.